# Python how to create a new column that measures proximity to a city?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geopy

I have a dataframe with Latitude and Longitude columns,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude':[47.5112, 47.7210, 47.7379, 47.5208, 47.6168],
                    'Longitude':[-122.257, -122.319, -122.233, -122.393, -122.045]})
```

How do I create a column that measures the distance towards a particular location with coordinates (47.631872, -122.217109)

In particular I'd like to use the `geodesic` function from `geopy` for the distance: `from geopy.distance import geodesic`. It takes in the inputs of 2 tuples containing latitudes and longitudes, and outputs the distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply`

```
location = (47.631872, -122.217109)
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda x:geodesic((x["Latitude"], x["Longitude"]), location), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think it should be `location = (47.631872, -122.217109)<br>
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda x:geodesic((x["Latitude"], x["Longitude"]), location), axis=1)`

Comment: @spidermarn you are correct, this is another option, hopefully you get what you need this time

Comment: @spidermarn Updated as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a new column within the DataFrame with the desired distance:

```
location = (40.5, 47.7) # example of coordinates of your desired location, change as needed

df["Distance To Location"] = geodesic((df["Latitude"],df["Longitude"]),location)
```

Your dataframe will now have a 3rd column with a pointer to a pandas Series of geodesic objects from each lat/long row and location coordinates provided.

Optionally if you only want the actual distance value (float) in say "miles" you can do something like this:

```
# To get the float value of the distance in miles
df["Distance To Location"] = geodesic((df["Latitude"],df["Longitude"]),location).miles
```

And it should save the float value in miles for each row directly into your dataframe.

Comment: I get the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` when I try your code

Comment: Check if you have NaN or empty Lat/long values, might want to cleanse/remove those first.

Comment: what version of pandas and python are you running?

Comment: python 3.6.8 and pandas 1.1.0

Comment: don't think its a version issue, although I am using python 3.8.1 but pandas 1.0.3, so are you storing the geodesic object in the column or transforming to miles or km value? I do not use geodesic but tested with a custom class and have no issues, did you also try `apply` with `lambda` function as the other answer suggests?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are not adding extra boolean logic like "and"/"or" in there? because that would be the main reason why you get a series ambiguous truth type error.

Comment: the other answer with `apply` and `lambda` works for me

Comment: yeah, if you are planning to store the geodesic object in the column then `apply` function is better for you. cheers!